# Elimination theory in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Does anyone know a good reference for elimination theory (Theorem 5.7A) mentioned in Hartshorne? The reference he gives is Van der Waerden modern algebra volume two, but it didn't feel locally readable. Can someone suggest a different reference?

Thanks. :)

Comment: What do you mean "locally readable"?...Anyways I think there is something on this in Eisenbud.

Comment: There's probably something in the "Algebraic Spaces" chapter of Lang's _Algebra_.

Comment: There is a short section on this topic in J. Milne’s notes on Algebraic Geometry. One may go to Milne’s page and download it.